# How to avoid getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'weekday_text' of undefined" error when some objects have the field and some don't?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm getting the sight information by making a GET request to google places API. Unfortunately, some sights have a `opening_hours` object field which itself has `weekday_text` and `open_now` fields BUT some of the sights don't so I get the error

```
<p v-if='sight.opening_hours && sight.opening_hours.open_now'>Open now</p>
<p v-if='sight.opening_hours && !sight.opening_hours.open_now'>Closed now</p>
<p v-if='sight.opening_hours && sight.opening_hours.weekday_text' v-for='day in this.sight.opening_hours.weekday_text'>{{ day }}</p>
```

Are my v-ifs not covering the case where `sight.opening_hours` and `sight.opening_hours.weekday_text` do not exists? I think the error comes from the v-for since if I remove it, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-with-v-for
v-if and v-for together is not recommended

```
<div v-if='sight.opening_hours && sight.opening_hours.weekday_text'>
  <p v-for='day in this.sight.opening_hours.weekday_text'>{{ day }}</p>
</div>
```

or if you don't need to print `div` then you can use `template`

```
<template v-if="sight.opening_hours && sight.opening_hours.weekday_text">
  <p v-for='day in this.sight.opening_hours.weekday_text'>{{ day }}</p>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks, combining v-if and v-for seems to have been the problem as you suggested.

Comment: yes `v-for` will have the preference first, you can use `v-if` if you need to check anything in `day`

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite your code like 'condition check on outer level and iteration inside'. You probably need `template` element.

```html
template(v-if="sight.opening_hours && sight.opening_hours.weekday_text")
  p(
    v-for="(day, index) in this.sight.opening_hours.weekday_text",
    :key="index"
  )
    | {{ day }}
```